# 'ConnectionString property has not been initialized' error when connecting to database

Tags: c#

I've just started programming in C# and I'm building a restaurant system. I created the login form, it works without error, but when I log in, I get an error when it should switch to the new form. The error is this.

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`

The code block giving the error is:

```cs
public bool personelEntryControl(int UserId, string password)
{
    bool result = false;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from PERSONELLER where ID=@Id and PAROLA=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

    try
    {
        if (con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
           con.Open();
        }
        result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) 
    {
        string hata = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting the connection string?

Comment: Set the connection string (the thing that contains the server name, database to connect to and either an integrated security flag or a username and password). You can set this when creating the connection. As a parameter in the constructor: var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

This is how the SqlConnection knows what server and database to connect to.

Comment: Well, you are only doing `con = new SqlConnection()` but not setting any information how to connect (ie a connectstring) ...

Comment: As a aside - you've already picked up a bad habit. There should never be any doubt in your code about the state a connection is in. Here, you just created the connection object and so it won't be anything other than closed. The more worrying situation where you might think it's needed is if you're *sharing* connection objects - when in fact it's the sharing that should be avoided, not not knowing what state the connection is in.

Answer (score 2):

- If this issue is related to `ConnectionString`, then you need to initialize the `SqlConnection` object with valid connection string that has details of `database connection`.
- You can initialize your connection string and `SqlConnection` as below, you can also initialize it in `App.config` file.

```
string connectionString = "DataSource=serverName;InitialCatalog=databaseName;User ID=username;Password=password";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Replace below terminology with valid values.

- `serverName` : Name or database address of your server.
- `databaseName` : Name of your database.
- `username` : Valid username, to authenticate server.
- `Password` : Valid password, to authenticate server.